# Error: unable to open Unable to open %s.shp or %s.SHP

Tags: shapefile, api, c

I am using c shapelibrary (http://shapelib.maptools.org/) SHAPE API for creating and reading shapefiles. I am able to create a new shapefile using SHPcreate(). However I am unable to read it using SHPopen() function. Even if I give the full path to the .shp it doesn't open. I tried one of the test1.shp files in my cpp program however it still didn't work.

These are the lines.

```
#include "shapefil.h"

SHPHandle pfile; 
pfile = SHPOpen("xx.shp", "r+b");
```

I also used

```
pfile = SHPOpen("xx.shp", "rb");
```

and all the .shx .prj .dbf were in the same folder as .shp. I am unable to figure out what would be the issue. Can anyone assist. These commands work fine in linux. However I need to use it in c++ project. Can anyone suggest on if I need to enable any macros. or anything.